# VS Empty Project makes Exception (Exception thrown at 0x..)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, startup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNPET.png)

I want to remove Exceptions below, But Don't know how to

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFADD50CD29 in TestProject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x0000005C0A3AD420.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFADD50CD29 in TestProject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x0000005C0A3AE540.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFADD50CD29 in TestProject.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x0000005C0A3AE2DC.
```

It's just an empty project

Comment: On a clear disk you can seek forever.

Comment: Ask [this company](https://en.fasoo.com/products/fasoo-enterprise-drm/) for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These exceptions are caused by a third-party software Fasoo DRM. It injects its code into your app. As Google says, Fasoo Enterprise DRM - Persistent Threat Protection, perhaps is some kind of antivirus software. Uninstall or disable it.